# Returning to previous value of unbound Access combobox

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

When a user selects a value from an unbound combobox, I want to carry out some checks. If the checks fail, I want to the combobox to return to the previously selected value.

I've tried using .oldvalue on events :-

```
On Change
Before Update
After Update
```

...but I believe this won't work as the combobox is unbound?

Comment: That's right. OldValue only has a meaning for bound controls. So, when entering the combobox, set a property or variable of the form to the value of the combobox, and retrieve this if the validation fails.

Comment: @Gustav On what event would I get the original value of the combobox?

Comment: As I wrote: Enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gustav correctly said, you can store the control's .Value in the .Tag property on Enter so if the validation fails, you can restore it.

```
'Save Value to Tag
Private Sub Combo_Enter()
    With Me.Combo
        .Tag = .Value
    End With
End Sub

'Validate and revert
Private Sub Combo_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not True Then  'Your validation
        With Me.Combo
            .Value = .Tag
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```